# Wiring question - 3 lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, light-fixture

Trying to get a really precise answer about what to do with each wire. I got some answers before but they were not specific enough and had run on sentences I could not make sense of. I am very handy, have installed lights before. This one is puzzling me. It was one of the loose ends that the contractor did not do. He's already been paid. Too busy to come back or return calls.

I have three lights and two switches, and a bunch of resulting wires. The switches are wired up, so we're good there. The lights are not. I just have wires and don't know where they ought to go.

Using my tester stick I have only found 1 hot black wire between all three lights.

I did a continuity test.

If anybody could help with letting me know the right combo of what to hook up to what I would greatly appreciate it. I've taken some pictures and I am hoping that somebody can help with this information.

The power is off at the breaker when I am working, and I do safety checks to make sure I am not working with live current.

Thanks so much!

If you could explain in really specific layman terms which # wires to connect to what, or each other, I would really appreciate it. Simple terms like how you might talk to a small child or Golden Retriever. LOL. Thanks guys!

[image]

Comment: You should edit your original question and add this information to it instead of having questions all over the place.

Comment: It got answered but I did not understand the answer. Hoping with this more detailed post, that somebody can be more precise with what I should do.

Comment: I deleted the other question so as not to get confusing. if anybody can answer this one with the wires actually numbered I would be grateful for the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While you have provided some good info in your graphic, putting text directly into the post instead of having it be "graphic text" that cannot be edited would be helpful. You can interleave text and images here so there's less clicking and having to switch back and forth between tabs in the browser. I do comment you on the excellent labeling of your wires - that will make it easier for people to refer to things. I've got to ask, just to be sure - you said you did all this with the power off - how do you expect to find live wires with the breaker turned off?

Comment: HI FreeMan, I had found the live wire when the breaker was ON. However, I turned the breaker OFF to test the continuity. Thanks.